# Woocommerce single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am making an e-commerce website with wordpress and there are a few things that are stressing me. I would like to have a custom single page for each product category. How do I do that?

Comment: What did you do and what is your problem when doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new page on Wordpress, and add a shortcode there:

`[product_category category="category-slug"]` - just replace the "category-slug" with the category slug of yours. You can view the slug at Product > Categories in the admin menu.

This shortcode will display all products in a specified category. You can repeat this and create as many pages for as many categories as you want.